# Average wins per player

Tags: google-sheets

I'm not really good with Java, even less with Sheets and i need help for this :

I want to create a list of average win of players using a list with several other players :

Example (I want to get the average on the right):

[image: Example of spreadsheet]

Conceptually this would be "for each player, see if the player match and if he won (ratio 1:1) then continue until there is no more game (or the end of the array)".

It's for a team game and we use Google Sheets a lot for it; I wanted some stats too.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript != Java.

Additionally, there's no JavaScript involved here if you're just using Sheets.

```
=AVERAGE(COUNTIF(A2:A7, "Win")/COUNTA(A2:A7))
```

**Steps for understanding:**

1. `COUNTIF` all cells in a range containing the text "Win".
2. `COUNTA` all cells in the same range, regardless of what they contain.
3. Calculate the `AVERAGE` of those two values using the built-in function.

`A2:A7` is just an example and should be replaced with whatever range your `RESULT` column takes up.